# Would it be a conflict of interest if I worked at company B while I was owner of company A in the same industry?

Tags: conflict-of-interest

I was a part owner at company A. (My husband is still a director there.) At the same time, I worked at company B in the same industry and area, and also in a sales position.

Would this be a conflict of interest?

Comment: What does your contract at Company B say about this?

Comment: They said they don’t see a problem but the business partner does at company a and no  disclosure was made about working at company b

Comment: Forget what he "says", what does the contract say?

Comment: Business partner wife working at company b.  Did not disclose to other business partner she was working there but was getting referrals from her.  Found out through   3rd party.  Shareholders agreement states cannot work for a competitor when terminated but she is still a shareholder at company a.  Company b have stated they don’t see a conflict. Hope that makes sense

Comment: Wife also worked in company a first

Comment: Are they publicly trading competitors?

Comment: Private limited company

Comment: I think you answered your own question

Comment: Argument is volume builder v custom builder. But we are doing off the plan at the custom builder too. Display home 4 houses apart. I think there is a conflict and also non disclosure is a breach of shareholders agreement

Comment: There was a question a few months ago were the son was going to leave his parents business to get more experience working for the competition. I imagine this situation has similarities, does someone know the link? - Thanks.

Comment: Please provide a clear summary of all the information you've put in comments into your question, using proper sentences and capitalisation. At the moment, you're not going to get an answer to this because nobody can actually work out what the situation is.

Answer (score 2):

> What if I was a part owner at company A (husband is director still)but
>   worked at company b in the same industry and area and also in a sales
>   position Wouldn’t this be a conflict of interest.

Yes, it might very well be a conflict of interest.

Company B may very well fire you if they find out, particularly if they have conflict of interest rules written into their contracts or HR documents.

At the same time you may be competing with yourself. You are likely either disadvantaging Company A to the benefit of Company B, or disadvantaging Company B to the benefit of Company A.

Very few companies would permit this conflict if it becomes known. Likely neither Company A nor Company B would approve.